# How many elements can a Loki sequence have?

Tags: c++, boost-mpl, typelist, c++-loki

I know boost MPL list or vectors have maximum lengths which are semi definable but after about 30 elements the compiler hates me. How many elements can a Loki sequence have and is it user definable?

Comment: AFAIR it's made up to 20 or so, may be 25. Alaxandrescou had shown a way how to extend this.

Comment: Can you upgrade your compiler to have variadic templates at your disposal ? It would alleviate much of your woes.

Comment: @MatthieuM. not yet sadly, does this make boost::mpl::list be able to handle drasticly larger lists ? (like 100) I had a problem a while back with lots of types needing to all be part of a variant which I couldn't use boost::variant for because of the mpl::list size constraint. I would be cool if it works when I upgrade my compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implementation](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00681.html) shows 18 hidden template parameters, so this should be the upper limit

```
     template
     <
         typename T1  = NullType, typename T2  = NullType, typename T3  = NullType,
         typename T4  = NullType, typename T5  = NullType, typename T6  = NullType,
         typename T7  = NullType, typename T8  = NullType, typename T9  = NullType,
         typename T10 = NullType, typename T11 = NullType, typename T12 = NullType,
         typename T13 = NullType, typename T14 = NullType, typename T15 = NullType,
         typename T16 = NullType, typename T17 = NullType, typename T18 = NullType
     > 
     struct MakeTypelist { /* stuff */ };
```